# While i compile and about to push element I get Segmentation error

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

While i compile and about to push element I get Segmentation error.
What is segmentation error?Can anyone explain me about such type of error.
Is it related to memory handling?

```
#include<iostream>

#define MAX 10
using namespace std ;


typedef struct
{
int items[MAX] ;
int top=-1;

}node;


int isFull(node *s){
if (s->top==MAX-1)
{
    return 1 ;

}

else{
    return 0;
}
}


int isEmpty(node *s){
if (s->top==-1)
{
    return 1 ;

}

else{
    return 0;
}



}

void push(node *s , int );
void pop(node *s);




void push(node *s , int n ){
if (isFull(s))
{
    cout<<"Stack overflow"<<endl;


}
else{

    s->items[++(s->top)]=n;

}



}


void pop(node *s){
    if(isEmpty(s)){
        cout<<"The stack is empty";

    }
    else{
cout<<"item poppe is "<< s->items[s->top--] <<endl;
    }
}





int main(){

int num, choice ;
node *s ;
int flag ;

do{


    cout<<"Enter your choice"<<endl;

    cout<<"1.Push"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.POP"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;

    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
        case 1 :
        cout<<"Enter the number to insert "<<endl;
        cin>>num;
        push(s,num );
        break ;

        case 2 :
        pop(s);
        break ;



        default:
        cout<<"Error";
        break;
    }
}
while(flag!=0);

return 0 ;


}
```

ERROR IS :

Segmentation fault

```
                                                                                                                                    Program finished with exit code 139
```

What is a segmentation fault? Is it different in C and C++? How are segmentation faults and dangling pointers related?

Comment: Inside `main()`, `node *s;`: `s` is not initialized

Comment: You have a pointer variable `s` in the `main` function. But *where does it point?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define a *pointer to a node* (actually a complete stack), but you do not create a *node object* to which this pointer can point to. Hence, you dereference an uninitialized pointer, which yields undefined behaviour (e.g. a segfault).

Instead of

```
node *s ;
...
push(s,num );
```

Write

```
node s ;
...
push(&s,num );
```

Or

```
node *s = new node();  // or = malloc(sizeof(node)) in C
...
push(s,num );
...
// once the stack is not used any more:
delete s; // or free(s) in C.
```

such that you create an actual object, which's address you can pass then.

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation error means you have accessed some area of memory that you shouldn't.

In your case it's because the pointer `s` is uninitialised.

In this case the right thing to do is not use a pointer for your stack, and to use the address-of operator `&` to get the pointer you need.

```
int main(){
...
node s; // not a pointer
...
        push(&s, num); // use & operator
...
        pop(&s); // use & operator
```

Pointers never 'magically' point at objects, you have to allocate the objects either by declaring variables or by using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a pointer to a node, but you did not create a node object to which this pointer can point to. Hence, you defined as an uninitialized pointer, which yields undefined behaviour (e.g. a segfault).

Again a segmentation error means you have accessed some area of memory that you shouldn't.

In your case it's because the pointer **"s"** is uninitialised.Here you have to give **"&"** which is the address of the operator.

### You have to edit your code like this.

```
int main () {
node s;
push (&s, num);
pop (&s);
```